# Calculating sum based on quarters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum of totals based on quarter system.
`[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]` - Initial array

The result I am looking for is 
`[60, 150, 70, 80, 90]`
Where `Q1 = 10+20+30 = 60`
`Q2 = 40+50+60 = 150`
Q3 will be complete only if pass in October value.

I am confused with the logic I have

```js
var adata = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
process(adata, "Sept 2014");

function process(adata, date){
    var today = new Date(date) || new Date();
    var aQuarter = [];
 var tempQuarter = [];
    var aSum = [];
    //var quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3)/3);
    for(var i = 0; i<= today.getMonth(); i++) {
        aQuarter.push(adata[i]);
    }
    tempQuarter = adata.slice();
    if(tempQuarter.length > 3) {
  var i = 0;
        var sum = [];
  while(i <= 2) {
   sum[i] = aQuarter.shift();
   i++;
  }
        console.log(sum);
  aQuarter.unshift(sum);
 }
    if(tempQuarter.length > 6){
  var i = 0;
        var sum = [];
  while(i+1 <= 3) {
   sum[i] = aQuarter.shift();
   i++;
  }
  aQuarter.unshift(sum);
 }
    console.log(aQuarter);
    if(tempQuarter.length > 9){
  var i = 0;
  while(i+2 <= 4) {
   sum[i] = aQuarter.shift();
   i++;
  }
 }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaadn7w6/3/)

Comment: You say the result should be.. `[60, 150, 80, 80, 90]`. Dont you mean `[60, 150, 70, 80, 90]`?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I meant `[60, 150, 70, 80, 90]`. Updated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry played around with the fiddle a bit and got this to get your results, will it work for you?

```
var adata = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
console.log("Sept 2014");
process(adata, "Sept 2014");

console.log("April 2014");
process(adata, "April 2014");

console.log("March 2014");
process(adata, "March 2014");

console.log("December 2014");
process(adata, "December 2014");

function process(adata, date){
    var today = new Date(date) || new Date();

    // reults array init
    var tempArray = [];
    var eachQuarterAmount = 3;
    // Limit the values to January to today as defined by the date param
    var aDataUpToPoint = adata.slice(0,today.getMonth() + 1);
    console.log(aDataUpToPoint);

    for (var i = 0; i < aDataUpToPoint.length; i+=eachQuarterAmount) {
    // increment every 3 values

        if (typeof aDataUpToPoint[i+eachQuarterAmount] != 'undefined') {
            // If there's anything after (ie if there's Oct) then total previous values up using reduce
            tempArray.push(aDataUpToPoint.slice(i,i+eachQuarterAmount).reduce(function(total, num){ return total + num },0));
        } else {
            // If the hunt for red October failed just tack on whatever remains
            for (; i < aDataUpToPoint.length; i++) {
                // uses the same loop contol variable as the parent to complete the search in both cases, picks up where it left off
                tempArray.push(aDataUpToPoint[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(tempArray);
}
```

Edit: reduce some magic numbers... sorta.

Note: Just realized you were doing something with a date param... so really my `adata.length` should probably be replaced with `today.getMonth()`

Edit 2: sliced aData down to work within a date range, added a +1 to the data set and removed the +1 from the look ahead.

Comment: @user525146 sorry I got tunnel blind and forgot the first part of your script regarding the date param... I think you can fix that easily and I made a note about it, but ya, not sure if I totally understood your intent there

Comment: I updated the code to `today.getMonth()`, its giving me different result  in different cases, `http://jsfiddle.net/8f2k679x/`

Comment: @MaxZoom, it works for me `Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` in latest chrome

Comment: You are right, not sure why the Firefox debugger complained about.

Comment: @DaveGoten If I pass in the date as `April`, it has to show `[60, 40]`, if its `march`, since its not a complete quarter I need to see the array as `[10,20,30]`. Its not possible with the above code.

Comment: @user525146 Yes I see now, I'll edit the code above in a sec.

Comment: @DaveGoten I am trying to create a table with same logic, but instead I have column names like Q1, Q2, Jul, Aug, Sep etc `http://jsfiddle.net/q8ftcj57/'. I am wondering if this can be simplified

Comment: @user525146 instead of making an array like `tempArray.push(aDataUpToPoint[i]);` update an object with `{index:value} ` to get a result like `{Q1:50, Q2:150, 7:70, 8:80, 9:90}` then loop through the object with a `for (i in obj) { }` loop. The `i` there will be Q1, then Q2, then 7, then 8, then 9. You can then build the table headers first with the I's then the data with the values of `obj[i]`

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit shorter version with loop to sum quarters value only. Unused elements are concatenated at the end.

```
var adata = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
process(adata, "Sept 2014");

function process(adata, date) {
  var today = new Date(date) || new Date();
  var QUOTER = 3;
  var month = today.getMonth();
  var limit = (month > adata.length) ? adata.length : month;
  var aQuarter = []; // quater sum array
  var sum = 0;       // gather sum for each quarter
  for (var i=0; i < limit; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(adata[i]);
    if ((i+1) % QUOTER == 0) {
      aQuarter.push(sum);
      sum = 0;
    }
  }
  var usedElements = aQuarter.length * QUOTER;
  if (adata.length > usedElements)
    aQuarter = aQuarter.concat(adata.slice(usedElements));

  console.log("On " + today + " the sums are " + aQuarter);
}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maxZoom/7uxx802o/5/) that you can play with date setting.

Comment: I'm trying to create a table with column names with similar logic above. I have this code, `http://jsfiddle.net/q8ftcj57/`. Can this be further simplified ?